# Navigate to previous fragment and destroy present fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation, android-navigation-graph

I've implemented many fragments using the navigation graph. Consider I have A-> B-> C-> D
where A, B, C, D are the fragments in order of implementation. Now I am on fragment D and I want to move to fragment C on click of a button in D. How do I do that? Also when I reach fragment C and press the back button it should take me to fragment B. I want to implement navigation to the previous fragment and destroy the current fragment. i.e Move to C from D and destroy D(not want it on the press of a back button).

Answer (score 1):

u can use below code you can get current position of your viewpager :

```
int position = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
//or
Fragment fragment = adapter.getItem(position);
```

so also can use this code to dynamicity go which tab u want, so in button click listener set this code:

```
viewpager.setCurrentItem(specificFragmentPosition);
// like this: viewpager.setCurrentItem(2);
```

and for second question u have to override onBackPressed() method in your fragment
this method calls when user clicked in back button...

so u can add this code again in your onBackPressed() method,

```
viewpager.setCurrentItem(specificFragmentPosition);
```